# Unable to start windows

Tags: system-installation, mount, mountpoint

As you can see from my question I'm really noob with Ubuntu. I have installed my Ubuntu on my computer. I was thinking that I will be able to make choice between Ubuntu and Windows after reboot the system. Now seems like I made a mistake.

I will try to explain what exactly I did:

Under Windows operating system I made a separate disk for Ubuntu. I run the installation files for Ubuntu from the USB. I select the drive which I made before for Ubuntu and then I selected file system ext4.

The device for boot loader installation I choose the same drive that I have made for the operating system Ubuntu. Probably here is the problem but I'm not sure.

I have to inform you also that my Windows system was using also "system reserved" although inside of the drive I couldn't find any saved files.

Probably is important to know also that when I start the installation wizard for Ubuntu the system was unable to find any other operation system in my machine although that I had installed Windows already.

I tried to use boot-repair-disk but I couldn't start because I need to make a bootable USB with the ISo but unfortunately I can't start UNetbootin.

I hope that you can understand what I mean even with my bad English.

Regards!

Comment: What version of Windows do you use?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Hold Shift during Ubuntu boot. If that doesn't bring up the menu, press Ctrl+Alt+Delete while seeing Ubuntu's bootsplash. Can you access Windows from the menu appearing? (Maybe under *Other Operating Systems*) Basically you **should** be able to select your OS on boot.

Comment: Hi I tried with Ctrl+Alt+Delete but there is no Windows from the menu.

Comment: Boot Ubuntu, open a terminal, and run `sudo update-grub`. Maybe your Windows will be in the menu afterwards.

Comment: I did and now everything is there. I could start my Windows. Thank you!

Comment: See my answer to make the menu appear permanently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Boot Ubuntu
2. Open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
3. Edit the file */etc/defaut/grub*: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
4. Change the line `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` to any value you like. The number you give here is how long this menu should be shown (in seconds) before booting the default entry, e.g. `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` for 10 seconds. If you want the menu to stay infinitely, until you select something, set the line to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1`.
5. Save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.
6. Run `sudo update-grub` another time.

The next time you boot, the menu will show up for the time span you set in step 4.

Comment: To be honest even without this changes the menu appear automatically. Anyway this post was useful for me. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

you can recover your windows using windows CD or Bootable USB. if you do not overwrite alredy.

if you have windows 8 or 7 CD than you can recover your windows.

for this you have to follow this steps.

Boot from the Windows install or repair CD appropriate to you version of Windows.

**For Windows 8 or 7:**

1 – Boot from repair disc > Choose Keyboard type > click Troubleshoot > click Advanced options > choose Automatic Repair
if that fails then use:
2 -Boot from Recovery disc or Install disc

-Boot from repair disc > Chose Keyboard type > click Troubleshoot > click Advanced options > choose Command Prompt

or

-Boot from Install disc > Click Next > click Repair your computer > click Troubleshoot > click Advanced options > choose Command Prompt

type > bootrec /fixmbr (writes mbr but does not overwrite partition table)

type > bootrec /fixboot (writes new boot sector to system partition)

type > bootrec /scanos (scans for other OS’s that you might want to add to bcd)

(personally I find the above unneeded and only use the last step)

type > bootrec /rebuildbcd (scans for other OS’s, unlike rebuildbcd it allows you to select the OS’s you want to add to bcd)

Reboot

i hope that will work for you.

Comment: But then he can't boot Ubuntu any more.

Comment: after recover of windows he can install Ubuntu again.if he want to recover windows.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the CD for my copy of Windows. I was using an USB but I don't have it. Is there another solution ?

Comment: First try brining up the GRUB menu as described in the comment to your question.

Comment: you can create windows 7 or 8 bootable USB from other friend laptop/PC.

Comment: Well I will need to find another computer. I was wondering it's possible to make the boot USB under Ubuntu with the boot-repairs-disk or is just better to make a Rescue disk for Windows 7? If I get appropriate instructions how to make it in Ubuntu the bootable USB I can try.